# How do I attach images in Pelican?

Tags: python, pelican

I am trying to attach an image in Pelican, following the documentation [here](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#linking-to-static-files). Here is the markdown:

```
![energy]({filename}images/energy.png)
```

and the pelicanconf.py:

```
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'pdfs']
ARTICLE_URL = 'blog/{date:%Y}/{date:%m}/{slug}.html'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = 'blog/{date:%Y}/{date:%m}/{slug}.html'
```

The `.html` files are written into `output/YYYY/MM/` directory where the markdown gets interpreted as:

```
<img alt="energy" src="{filename}/images/energy.png"/>
```

in the `.html` while the images are written into `output/images` folder.

So the HTML files cannot find the images. How do I fix it? Ideally, I would like to store the images in the same folder as the `.html` files (I think that is what `{attach}` does).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using `{attach}` and not `{filename}`.

Also, if you have `energy.png` in the same folder as `blogpost.md` then {attach} will work. With your example you must have `energy.png` in the images subfolder.

The documentation states that you should be careful of images being attached to multiple pages. If `energy.png` is **only** being `{attached}`-ed to `blogpost.md` then it will get published alongside the resulting HTML file. Otherwise it may be moved to a place were `otherblogpost.md` won't expect it to be, unless all files are in the same directory, which is not going to happen in your case (where the resulting html files are in the date subfolders).

Comment: `{attach}` is not recognized at all; I get the following error message: `ERROR: Better Fig. Error: image not found: [~]/pelican/content/{attach}energy.png` when the image and markdown are in the same folder. I am using pelican 3.6.3, so that is strange.

Comment: Removed `Better figures` but now it cannot find the image: `WARNING: Unable to find energy.png, skipping url replacement.` I also tried putting it in `images/energy.png`, which is where I would prefer it go so as to not clutter the `content` directory.